# Angular 6 store session data

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6, session-state

I don't know which forum suits this question, so suggest me to move...

I do not want to store current user data in browser (cookie,session storage or local storage).
So what else options are there,

Heard about the redux- pattern ng-rx does it holds data even after refreshing the page, if yes where does it store the data.

I am very much new to angular and have experience with .net where we store data on server side using session or anything else like memcache etc.

I can only see one option to use any database to store data like firestore or anything else.

what else options I could adopt to store user sessions data or temporary data which should be available even user refresh the page.

Comment: you need to go server-side to store data outside of browser

Comment: why do you not want to store at browser?

Comment: Take a look at redis.

Comment: @MohamedSameer, that's is fine, But i want to know is there anything in angular which handles session by just configuring the server storage (anyone) credentials.